# Window VScode ssh development keep disconnecting from raspi server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

I was doing ssh development but I had been disconnected for a while. When I connect back it has this error

```
[12:57:26.116] [Forwarding server 55434] Got connection 1
[12:57:26.370] [Forwarding server 55434] Got connection 2
[12:57:58.216] [Forwarding server 55434] Got connection 3
[12:58:09.641] > client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
[12:58:09.664] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 43729: read ECONNRESET. Is the remote port correct?
[12:58:13.176] "install" terminal command done
[12:58:13.176] Install terminal quit with output: client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

Previously was connected normally but why suddenly got this error, anyone has some idea or solution?